# Passing a value to a hidden form input from an anchor using jQuery and custom attributes

Tags: jquery, forms, custom-attributes

I have a single-page website that has several anchor tags that display a modal window with a form. Each link should pass a value to the form using custom attributes (something like item-name="item 1").

The form should pick up the item-name attribute from the link it was called from, and filling in the hidden field.

The form is hidden within a div in the page, which is then displayed as a modal window.

How can I go about this? I'm using jQuery since this is a very basic page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be using data-attributes for this and call a function on the click that a) sets the value of the hidden field and b raises your modal. The following demontratees the passing of the data-attibute to the function on the click and then updating the hidden field value.

Also - you do not need jQuery for this - straight js is totes adequate.

You can also add you own logic to raise the modal.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-modal-link');

links.forEach(function(link){
  link.addEventListener("click", (e) => triggerModal(e.target))
})

function triggerModal(el) {
  const id = el.getAttribute('data-id');

  const field = document.querySelector('#hidden-field');
  field.value = id;
  
  // logic to raise the modal
  
 // console the input - just to show the hidden field is updating its value on the click
 
 console.log(field); // shows eg: <input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" value="1"></input>
}
```

```css
a { color: blue;}

a + a { margin-left: 32px}
```

```html
<a data-id="1" class="trigger-modal-link">option 1</a>

<a data-id="2" class="trigger-modal-link">option 2</a>

<input type="hidden" id="hidden-field"/>
```

If you did want to use jQuery - it owuld look like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.trigger-modal-link').click(function() {
  const id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  const field = $('#hidden-field');
  field.val(id);
  console.log(field[0]);
  })
}); // gives eg : <input type="hidden" id="hidden-field" value="1"></input>
```

```css
a { color: blue;}

a + a { margin-left: 32px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-id="1" class="trigger-modal-link">option 1</a>

<a data-id="2" class="trigger-modal-link">option 2</a>

<input type="hidden" id="hidden-field"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I know I don't really need jQuery, but since I'm already loading the library to display the modal window I though I might as well just take advantage of it.